# Rails Single table inheritance (STI) with the User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, single-table-inheritance, sti

Building a small reservation site. There are `users` (who login and work with the site) and there are `guests` who are being assigned to `rooms`. `users` can be (are?) `guests` but not all `guests` are also `users`.

My initial inclination was to set up a `belongs_to` / `has_one` relationship between `user` & `guest` but maybe STI would work here? Being as users & guests have `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` etc. does it make sense to set up the model such that, say, `user` and `guest` both inherit from `person`?

I will roll my own simplistic authentication so the only additional fields `user` is likely to have are `password_digest`, `roles_mask` and a `icon_color`.

Any suggestions? I only ask because things can get tricky around authentication, authorization & whatnot.

Appreciate any ideas/tips!

Comment: I'd go with Devise with actual different models for Users and Guests

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach here would be to, as suggested, stick to STI.  You can, for example, setup a single `devise` `User` model as well as apply ACL with `CanCan` and define roles for your users.

`CanCan`'s ability spec will determine which resources are accessible and what are not.  The advantage here is that users can be guests, and depending on how you setup your ACL, guests can be prevented from having `admin` like access.

However, Jesse's suggestion of going two separate Devise models is also a good idea as this ensures their sessions are separate.  This is more straightforward to implement as you can then setup a User-specific ACL and Guest-specific ACL accordingly.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan